# PHP: How can I call child methods from the base class?

Tags: php, static-methods

From my understanding, it is good practice to not give a class too many responsibilities and good to split into sub classes, I am new to programming, so my idea was to do the following:

```
<?php

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{

    public static function child()
    {

        echo "Child";   

    }

}

class ParentClass
{


    public static function parentF()
    {

        echo "Parent";  

    }


}

ParentClass::child();
```

However, that fails because the Parent does not have access to the child function. From what I am describing, what should I be doing instead? My goal is to learn how to split a big class into multiple to make things easier to maintain.

Comment: You can use reflection, but it's not about OOP way.

Comment: How should I be doing it then?

Comment: What do you want to achieve at the very end?

Comment: In relation, why it fails. Think about this problem like so. `Apollo 13` extends base class `TransportationUnit`, and so does it `Mazda 626`. Now you want to call a static method **TransportationUnit::go()**. What it should call - `Apollo 13::ignite_rocket_fuel()` or `Mazda 626::start_a_starter()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can only access their parent like you concluded, not the other way around. Extending make the parent functions available in the child.

So what is possible is:

```
ChildClass::parentF();
```

Comment: Is there a better way to split functionality into other classes from a base/parent class?